# Can I bring vaccines (needles) in my carry on?

Tags: health, hand-luggage

I have to have a few vaccines injected during my holiday, so i was wondering whether or not I can bring my vaccines with me in my carry on. There is a needle on the vaccine.

Comment: Where are you flying from, and on what airline?  Rules can vary by country and by carrier.

Comment: This can't be generally answered until you edit it to provide the airports involved. Rules are not identical around the world. There is usually a mechanism to allow medical supplies through but what documentation you need is not always the same everywhere. Voting to put on hold for now.

Answer (score -1):

yes, you have permission to carry these with you but on vehicle or travelling on feet but you are not allowed to carry these in you hand bag with you while flying although, you carry these vaccines in your Equipment which is in other sector of plane and you are also informed by the inspectors in airport